# How can I add a placeholder to a random Int then pull a single digit from that Int in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and programming all together.. I am trying to make a program that ciphers a number for the user. The user inputs 5 digits separately so I add them together to get a total. I need to pull the first digit and second digit of the total and enter it into (firstDigit+key)%10  and  (secondDigit+key)%10. Then need to combine the answer to each equation together.

- My total needs to be two digits, so even if the user enters all 1's which would total to be 5, I need it to be displayed and seen as 05 so that both equations have a digit to use. It needs to be two digits. I cant seem to figure how to enter a place holder. I was thinking about trying to use:

  ```
  if (total < 10)
  ```

but then what?

- Secondly, the method I used below seems like a terrible way to pull a single digit from a number. I think I changed the int total into a string so I can use .substring to pull the digits, then converted back to an int. Surprisingly it works. Is there a better way to do this knowing that the number is random?

  ```
    String totalString = Integer.toString(total); 
    String stringDigit1 = totalString.substring(0,1); 
    String stringDigit2 = totalString.substring(1,2); 

    int firstDigitInt1 = Integer.parseInt(stringDigit1); 
    int firstDigitInt2 = Integer.parseInt(stringDigit2); 

    int encodedDigit1 = (firstDigitInt1+key)%10; 
    int encodedDigit2 = (firstDigitInt2+key)%10; 

    System.out.println("Your encoded Number is: " + encodedDigit1 + encodedDigit2);
  ```

Comment: `int firstDigit  = total % 10, secondDigit = (total / 10) % 10;`

Comment: What do you mean by "placeholder?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method for obtaining the individual digits is good, and if you want to maintain it I believe your intuition is correct, it should suffice to say:

```
if (total < 10) {
    firstDigitInt1 = 0
}
```

This will work out with your following math.

Your method with substrings is far from terrible, but in case you wanted something more sleek you can instead say:

```
int Digit1 = total / 10;
int Digit2 = total % 10;
```

Here, you can take advantage of integer truncation (where an integer won't remember decimal places) to get the first digit, which also solves the first problem: 5 / 10 = 0 (in terms of ints). For the second digit, it suffices to say modulo 10, as it is the remainder once the total is divided by 10.

Comment: This assumes that total < 100

Comment: Wow the method to pull each digit seems way to easy and less complicated. 2 lines instead of my 5. I implemented this and works great. Thanks!

Comment: The numbers the user can enter is only 0-19 so total will not reach 100. Should have stated that in the post. Thanks for the input for future projects though. Thanks tg.